# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() on ID?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, null

Whenever i want to update my data it keep crashing. The error always on my id epecially when i declare the database.child(refering to id) ? i hope there is solution on my problem.

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEzB7.png)

This is my code **UpdateShelterActivity**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            txtfvName.setText(bundle.getString("fvName"));
            txtHelp.setText(bundle.getString("typeSOS"));
            txtfvAddress.setText(bundle.getString("sosAddress"));
            txtStatus.setText(bundle.getString("sosStatus"));
            txtRemarkfv.setText(bundle.getString("victimRemark"));
            txtRemarkres.setText(bundle.getString("rescueRemark"));
            txtPhoneNum.setText(bundle.getString("fvPhoneNum"));
            sosId = bundle.getString("sosId");
        }

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               setdata();
                updatedata();
                startActivity(new Intent(updateSosFvActivity.this, sosListFvActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public void setdata(){
        txtfvName.setText(fvName);
        txtHelp.setText(typeSOS);
        txtfvAddress.setText(sosAddress);
        txtStatus.setText(sosStatus);
        txtRemarkfv.setText(victimRemark);
        txtRemarkres.setText(rescueRemark);
        txtPhoneNum.setText(fvPhoneNum);

    }

    public void updatedata() {

        fvName = txtfvName.getText().toString().trim();
        typeSOS = spinHelp.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        sosAddress = txtfvAddress.getText().toString().trim();
        sosStatus = spinStatus.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        victimRemark = txtRemarkfv.getText().toString().trim();
        rescueRemark = txtRemarkres.getText().toString().trim();
        fvPhoneNum = txtPhoneNum.getText().toString().trim();

        HashMap p = new HashMap<>();

        p.put("fvName", fvName);
        p.put("typeSOS", typeSOS);
        p.put("sosAddress", sosAddress);
        p.put("sosStatus", sosStatus);
        p.put("victimRemark", victimRemark);
        p.put("fvPhoneNum", txtPhoneNum);
        p.put("rescueRemark", rescueRemark);

        s = new sos(fvName,typeSOS,sosAddress,sosStatus,victimRemark,rescueRemark,fvPhoneNum);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SOS").child(sosId);
        reference.setValue(s).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(updateSosFvActivity.this, "Updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(updateSosFvActivity.this, sosListFvActivity.class));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(updateSosFvActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my **DetailActivity** (show detail of user)

```
public class DetailSosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtfvName,txtfvAddress, txtHelp,txtRemarkfv,txtStatus,txtRemarkres,txtPhoneNum;
    FloatingActionButton btnUpdate, btnDel;
    String sosId = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_detailsos);

        txtfvName = findViewById(R.id.txtfvName);
        txtfvAddress = findViewById(R.id.txtfvAddress);
        txtHelp = findViewById(R.id.txtHelp);
        txtRemarkfv = findViewById(R.id.txtRemarkfv);
        txtStatus = findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
        txtRemarkres = findViewById(R.id.txtRemarkres);
        txtPhoneNum = findViewById(R.id.txtPhoneNum);
        btnDel = findViewById(R.id.btnDel);
        btnUpdate = findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            sosId = bundle.getString("fvPhoneNumber");
            txtfvName.setText((bundle.getString("fvName")));
            txtHelp.setText((bundle.getString("typeSOS")));
            txtfvAddress.setText((bundle.getString("sosAddress")));
            txtStatus.setText((bundle.getString("sosStatus")));
            txtRemarkfv.setText((bundle.getString("victimRemark")));
            txtRemarkres.setText((bundle.getString("rescueRemark")));
            txtPhoneNum.setText(bundle.getString("fvPhoneNum"));

        }

        btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DetailSosActivity.this,updateSosFvActivity.class)
                        .putExtra("fvName",txtfvName.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("typeSOS",txtHelp.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("sosAddress",txtfvAddress.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("sosStatus",txtStatus.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("victimRemark",txtRemarkfv.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("rescueRemark",txtRemarkres.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("fvPhoneNum",txtPhoneNum.getText().toString())
                        .putExtra("sosId",sosId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        btnDel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SOS");

                reference.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        reference.child(sosId).removeValue();
                        Toast.makeText(DetailSosActivity.this, "Sos Deleted Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(DetailSosActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my error [When i trying to change the information or update the data it keep crashing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIjes.png)

Comment: Your `sosId` seems to be `null`. You are sending it via `.putExtra("sosId",sosId);` but I don't see it being retrieved in your `UpdateShelterActivity`.

Comment: I already put my sosId on bundle but i still got same error

Comment: Are you sure the `sosId` is not null before using it in your reference? Please respond using @AlexMamo